# bash: How to determine the largest number (newest version) from: ls *.tar.gz | cut -c 2-4

Tags: bash, ls, sort, cut

Hi I'm trying to get the largest number (newest version) of a file,

I got a bunch of `tar.gz` files in a directory, versions of some software in the format `v${version_number}_software.tar.gz`, where `${version_number}` is a three digit number.

Running `ls *.tar.gz | cut -c 2-4` gives me this output:

```
100
102
684
696
705
```

What would I run next (or what should I change in the ls or cut syntax) to get the highest value (in this case, `705`)?

I tried some `grep`, `awk` and `sed` but I'm a bit out of my league...
Any clue would be appreciated!

Comment: Using `ls -v` will get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sheesh, I might have noticed that the highest value always comes out to the last line :-)

so:

```
ls -d -- *.tar.gz | cut -c 2-4 | tail -n 1
```

it is. Leaving this question on, for posterity

EDIT: but as Lambert has suggested below,

```
ls -d -- *.tar.gz | cut -c 2-4 |sort -n|tail -n 1
```

is better to be sure that the output of `ls` is sorted numerically (otherwise `V999.tar.gz` could come before `v100.tar.gz` in locales where the sort order is case-sensitive). Too bad he didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: That the highest value always comes last is because of the lexical order. You might consider to force numeric sorting by inserting the command `sort -n` between the `cut..` and `tail...` commands: `ls *.tar.gz | cut -c 2-4 |sort -n|tail -n 1`

Comment: Depending on the format of the version numbers, `-V` or `--version-sort` may be a better option than `-n` or `--numeric-sort`.   Note, though, IIRC `-V` is only available in GNU sort.

Comment: Hi Lambert, yours is a better solution. you wanna post it as an answer? I can't accept my own answer as correct anyway, before a couple of days have passed